# tfRecords with images as inputs and targets

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, data-analysis, tfrecord

I'm currently trying to create a tf.Records from some .png images stored locally.

Most examples I've seen on this is for a classification task, where the target values are classes. 
I'm trying to build a VAE, so my target values would also be images.

I found [this](https://www.skcript.com/svr/why-every-tensorflow-developer-should-know-about-tfrecord/) example on generating tf.Records:

```
# Converting the values into features
# _int64 is used for numeric values
def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))

# _bytes is used for string/char values
def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

tfrecord_filename = 'something.tfrecords'

# Initiating the writer and creating the tfrecords file.
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecord_filename)

# Loading the location of all files - image dataset
# Considering our image dataset has apple or orange
# The images are named as apple01.jpg, apple02.jpg .. , orange01.jpg .. etc.

images = glob.glob('data/*.jpg')
for image in images[:1]:
    img = Image.open(image)
    img = np.array(img.resize((32,32)))
label = 0 if 'apple' in image else 1
feature = { 'label': _int64_feature(label),'image': _bytes_feature(img.tostring()) }

# Create an example protocol buffer
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))

# Writing the serialized example.
writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

writer.close()
```

**Question**:
what should one change to save also images as target values?

Is it changing:

```
feature = { 'label': _int64_feature(label),'image': _bytes_feature(img.tostring()) }
```

to

```
feature = { 'label': _bytes_feature(img.tostring()),'image': _bytes_feature(img.tostring()) }
```

?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just save two images in a single example. And it usually 
a good idea to save image dimensions

```
features=tf.train.Features(feature={'height': _int64_feature(h),
                                    'width': _int64_feature(w),
                                    'channels': _int64_feature(c)
                                    'image_1': _bytes_feature(image1)
                                    'image_2': _bytes_feature(image2)
                                    }
                          ))
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
```

**Edit**

If I got you right:

```
list = np.array([image_1, image_2,...image_n])
images = np.split(np.fromstring(list.tostring()), number_of_images)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The images you are passing as features are `img.tostring()` or are the raw PIL images?

Comment: Also, afai understood, the above example saves just 1 of the images. How can I save all of the images in 1 tf.records? loop over all image values or just put the image list in the `_bytes_feature()`

Comment: Yes you need `img.tostring()`. I added one raw solution of how to pass list of images

Comment: Thanks a lot again, I've worked with TF before, but I'm a newbie with tf.records. 
So in your edit, the elements in the `list` np array are the file location or the file objects?

Comment: They are numpy arrays, which you get with something like `cv2.imread`